# PhoneGap android app need to get external sdcard path, but its return only internal sdcard path

Tags: javascript, android, cordova

i am using phonegap for android application to get external card,

i am using this code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
        <title>Hello World</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/index.css" type="text/css" />
        <script src="js/jquery.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
        <script src="cordova.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            window.appRootDirName = "app";
            document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);

            function onDeviceReady() {
                console.log("device is ready");
                window.requestFileSystem(LocalFileSystem.PERSISTENT, 0, gotFS, fail);
                alert(window.appRootDir.fullPath);

            }

            function fail() {
                console.log("failed to get filesystem");
            }



            function gotFS(fileSystem) {
                console.log("filesystem got");
                window.fileSystem = fileSystem;
                fileSystem.root.getDirectory(window.appRootDirName, {
                    create: true,
                    exclusive: false
                }, dirReady, fail);
            }

            function dirReady(entry) {
                window.appRootDir = entry;

                console.log("application dir is ready");
            }



        </script>
    </head>
    <body>


    </body>
</html>
```

Its returns `file://mnt/sdcard/app` - this is my internal phone storage path
the external path is `file://mnt/ext_card/app`

How can i get external card path in phonegap?

Comment: possible duplicate of [how to get the full path of sdcard directory in android phonegap with javascript?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18374115/how-to-get-the-full-path-of-sdcard-directory-in-android-phonegap-with-javascript)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally i found we can't get the external SD Card Path,

```
Environment.getExternalStorageState();
```

Its returns only Internal SD Card path

Reference:
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Environment.html#getExternalStorageDirectory()

Comment: so it's really impossible to write on removable sd card with phonegap?