# How to specify saving a file to an external SD card in a Cordova Android app?

Tags: android, cordova, android-sdcard, phonegap-cli

I’m working on a Cordova app that downloads large media files. Because the internal storage on some Android devices is limited, I want to give the user the option to save downloaded files on their external SD card.

Cordova-android specifies a way to be able to do this with the cordova-plugin-file using the cordova.file.externalRootDirectory hook, but I have not found it to work in my tests. Instead the device creates a pseudo SD card within internal memory and saves there.

How can I access the actual external SD card within Cordova? Has anyone done this successfully?

Is it possible to display a “File Manager” type dialog so that the user can navigate to their external SD card, and tap a button that will then give the app the local path to that SD card directory, so I can store the path and use it for future downloads?

Thanks for any insights.

Comment: Try this link :
http://stackoverflow.com/a/19005414/4010758

Comment: Use this links : http://www.santoshshinde.com/2015/02/save-imagefile-into-sdcard-in-android.html                             https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-file

Comment: @jay link is now working any other links ?