# How to show a jpg image file from sd card in phonegap?

Tags: javascript, android, cordova

What I am trying to do here is to show an jpg image from the data directory of the android phone, not an image captured by the phone camera. Here is my code I have got to so far:

```
document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);
function onDeviceReady(){
    window.requestFileSystem(LocalFileSystem.PERSISTENT, 0, onFileSystemSuccess);
}
function onFileSystemSuccess(fileSystem){
    fileSystem.root.getDirectory("../data", {create: false, exclusive: false}, dirSuccess);
}
function dirSuccess(getDir){
    getDir.getFile("test.jpg", {create: false, exclusive: false}, fileSuccess);
}
```

I have two things to be confirmed about here. Firstly, will my code get me to the desired image file?? I mean if there is any error so far?? And secondly, where I am stuck actually, What I need to do to show the image on the app page?? just write the image file name in the src of img tag under fileSuccess method?? or something else?? I am new to phonegap and javascript. May be it's a easy problem. But still, please help me. Thank you...:)

Comment: Look there: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18374115/how-to-get-the-full-path-of-sdcard-directory-in-andorid-phonegap-with-javascript

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by retrieving the Base64 encoding of the image using this [plugin](https://github.com/hazemhagrass/phonegap-base64) then assign it to image src property.